Unrecognized name error in Google Big Query
I am new to sql and am getting an "Unrecognized name" error when I try to run a query and I'm not sure how to fix it.
I have a large table that I am pulling certain columns from -- one of which is called DateTime where I had to convert timestamps that were a string data type into a date data type known as my_new_datetime so that I could run some calculations.
This is my code:
WITH ProcessedInfo AS (
SELECT
ID,
 DateTime,
  coalesce(
    safe.parse_timestamp('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z', DateTime),
    safe.parse_timestamp('%m%d%Y%H%M%S%p', DateTime)
  ) as my_new_datetime,
Value1, Value2,
 FIRST_VALUE(Value1) OVER(PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM my_new_datetime), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM my_new_datetime) ORDER BY my_new_datetime ASC) AS Value1_FirstDay_Month,
  LAST_VALUE(Value1) OVER(PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM my_new_datetime), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM my_new_datetime) ORDER BY my_new_datetime ASC) AS Value1_LastDay_Month,
 MAX(Value2) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM my_new_datetime), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM my_new_datetime)) AS Value2_Max_ID_Month
FROM `LargeTable` 
),

FinalResult AS (
 SELECT ID, my_new_datetime, Value1, Value2,
  (Value1_LastDay_Month - Value1_FirstDay_Month) AS Value1_Diff,
   Value2_Max_ID_Month
 FROM ProcessedInfo
)

SELECT * FROM FinalResult;

I don't believe there is anything wrong with my code, however when I try to run the query it gives me the error: Unrecognized name: my_new_datetime at [11:55]

Appears you cannot reference the aliased column in the same CTE. See the rows in your first CTE which use first_value and last_value and max windows functions. You'll need to re-write those sections. You're 2nd CTE should be fine.
